# In PHP, how to filter multiple types in topic api?

Tags: php, freebase

I know that filtering multiple types works this way:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d6lp?filter=/common/topic/notable_for&filter=/common/topic/alias
```

but when I have to write this in PHP, I am not sure how to go about it.

```
$service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic';
$mid = '/m/0d6lp';
$params = array('key'=>$API_KEY, 'filter' => '/common/topic/notable_for', 'filter' => '/common/topic/alias');
$url = $service_url . $mid . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

When I curl the $url, only the last filter (/common/topic/alias) takes effect, obviously because the 'filter' key comes twice in the array $params and only the value for the latest key is taken.

How do I construct the following url in PHP arrays?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d6lp?filter=/common/topic/notable_for&filter=/common/topic/alias
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure of what you want to do. If what you want is just to perform a query with multiple filters you can add them directly in the url string like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d6lp?key=$API_KEY&filter=/common/topic/notable_for&filter=/common/topic/alias

You don't need to use any array, just construct the url as a normal php string. 
If you still want to have the parameters in an array I would advice you to make a foreach loop through all the elements in the array to construct the string, after that use the string as the parameter for the curl.